# Extract signed integers from string in Java

Tags: java, string, split

Given a string of the form

```
string str= "-1@10@-1#10@-1@10#-1@10@-1"
```

the numbers in a row are separated by `'@'`  and the rows are separated by `'#'` 
so the above line computes to the following matrix :

```
-1     10    -1
 10    -1    10
-1     10    -1
```

Also the numbers can be any number( not necessarily -1 and 10) another example is

```
srting str= "1@10@1#10@2@10#1@10@1"
```

should compute to

```
  1     10     1
 10      2    10
  1     10     1
```

How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using the algorithm below:

- Split the string on the `'#'` sign, using `String`'s [`split(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method
- Make an array of arrays the size of the split
- For each string in the previous split, split the line on the `'@'` sign.
- Make an array the size of the inner split, and assign it to the corresponding index of the 2D array
- For each item in the inner split, use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), and assign consecutive integers to elements of the inner array

Answer (score -1):

The following code works fine

```
public class matrix{

public static void main(String []args)
{

    String string="-1@10@-1#10@-1@10#-1@10@-1" ;
    String[] rows = string.split("#");

    for(int j=0;j<rows.length;j++)  
    {    
        String[] cols= rows[j].split("@");
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows.length][cols.length];
        for(int k=0;k<cols.length;k++)
        {   
            matrix[j][k]=Integer.parseInt(cols[k]);
            System.out.print(matrix[j][k]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

giving output

```
-1  10  -1
10  -1  10
-1  10  -1
```